# Content isn't loading on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging

I am trying to understand why content on my portfolio page is no longer loading on the frontpage and on the resume page. https://farbodjahan.com/ I am looking for errors but the only thing populating is a `frontend-builder-plugin-style.min.css:1`  error when inspecting element. The content still appears there but fails to load. Any ideas?

Comment: Please read the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552), where the consensus answer is No.

Comment: 404 means file is not there. So is the file not there? Is the path wrong? Is there a typo in the name?

Comment: @epascarello oh wow I go to the site and its no longer valid https://1ts2q04d2l9x3g3h5v4cpx3s-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/plugins/divi-builder/includes/builder/styles/frontend-builder-plugin-style.min.css?ver=2.20.2. Anyway to retrieve the content before it was wiped and just create a local copy of it

Comment: My suggestion and its valid suggestion most cases. Please stop using word press to auto upgrade/migrate JS things. It does good job in adding new code but does massively crappy job in removing old code. issue seems to spawn from down the line with div builder js. Revisit your code base, and by the way if you run on responsive mode and do hard reset content seem to fall into place. definitely word press widget at work.

Comment: @VisualExstasy precisely the issue.

Comment: @Syed how do I retrieve the content of the 404 failed divi-builder?

Comment: Well CSS file would only create visual issues content would be thre all grumpy and what not. To retrieve the if you have copy of it then its do able upload to your location and update link. If you dont have copy then we are in though waters

Comment: CSS is network issue .... second issue is in JS with index.js at line 59 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier it is halting script on what eevr it is suppose to do for some off reasone

Comment: @syed I dont have a local copy of it and only located online......So guess my portfolio page is broken until wpengine fixes itself? Theres no website to show the content history of a site before a 404 error?

Comment: whence for way back machine they may have some indexed copy etc but not gurantted. meanwhile in the kingdom of WordPress there is always a plugin to solve mess of another plugin and then another plugin to sort the cleaner plugin. So I you might have to back trace and update where things work.

Comment: @Syed unfortunately this site isnt hosted on wordpress so I cant exactly download a plugin to resolve it.